# Add image alt to WP Post Thumbnails

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add the alt attribute to post thumbnails on my blog.

I get the alt text to echo, but not as an attribute, but as text!

```
  <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {$image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(),’thumbnail’ ); $image_alt = wpseoFocusKW();
    echo '<img width="100%" src="' . $image_src[0] . '" alt=' . $image_alt .' >';} ?></div></div>
```

You can see the issue here: http://benefacto.org/three-days-paid-volunteering-leave-an-update-from-rob-wilsons-office/

You will note I'm using the Yoast Keyword as the alt, which works fine.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Ben

Comment: you are missing the `"` on `alt` attribute

Comment: Thanks @sebastianbrosch I've updated it to include the "" but it doesn't make any difference. Weird!

Comment: you are also using back ticks instead of single quotes around `thumbnail`

Comment: Thanks @M.Doye! - It still doesn't add the alt to the image

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (only PHP part):

```
<?php 
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(),'thumbnail'); 
        $image_alt = wpseo_get_value('focuskw', $post->ID);
        echo '<img width="100%" src="'.$image_src[0].'" alt="'.$image_alt.'">';
    } 
?>
```

The content of the function `wpseoFocusKW()` looks like this:

```
function wpseoFocusKW()
{
    $focuskw = wpseo_get_value('focuskw', $post->ID);
    echo $focuskw;
}
```

> This function only echo the keyword, but don't return!
>   **Reference:** http://snipplr.com/view/67931/

You can create a **custom function or change the original** like this:

```
function wpCustomSeoFocusKW($return = false)
{
    $focuskw = wpseo_get_value('focuskw', $post->ID);

    if ($return) {
        return $focuskw;
    } else {
        echo $focuskw;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks so much Sebastian. What the key to making it return rather than echo?

Comment: replace `echo $focuskw;` with `return $focuskw;` on the function or create your own custom function.